# Can't read calls to the ACM mouseMoved method

Tags: java

I'm working through the Stanford CS106A lectures and have hit a snag in the breakout project.

After I `addMouseListeners()`, I cannot detect mouseMoved calls. 
However if I rename `mouseMoved()` to `mouseDragged()` or `mouseClicked()` or `mousePressed()` etc, it all updates correctly. Only the moved method does not work.
No errors or alerts, just doesn't detect the mouse being moved.
Any idea why that would happen?

```
public void run() {
    /* Add a listener for the mouse */
    addMouseListeners();
    label = new GLabel("Mouse x & y");
    add(label, 50, 50);

    /* Load the method to create the brick pattern */
    createBricks();
}

/** Detect a mouse move and update something */
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
    label.setLabel("Mouse: " + e.getX() + " , " + e.getY());
    paddle.setLocation(e.getX(), getHeight()-PADDLE_Y_OFFSET);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `addMouseMotionListeners();`. `addMouseListeners` is only for the functions that you were using.